# Align img/icon to the left of TOC entry using memoir

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, memoir

I'm trying to generate a toc whith different icon/img aligned to the left of  author + chapter block in the TOC.

Here the code snippet MWE, the image1.png is given bottom of the post :

```
 \documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % Subsection mit Zähler (1.1) versehen

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{}  } 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} } 

\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\settocdepth{chapter}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\leftskip0em\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\noindent\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\authortoc[1]{%
  \gdef\chapterauthor{#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\authortoctext{#1}}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\newcommand*{\img}[1]{%
    \raisebox{-.3\baselineskip}{%
        \includegraphics[
        height=30pt,
        width=30pt,
        ]{#1}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents* 
\authortoc{G. Blabla, A. Blabla}
\chapter{\protect\img{image-1.png}This an entry for chapter}
\authortoc{F. Blabla, U. Blabla, M.Blabla,F. Blabla, U. Blabla, M.Blabla,F. Blabla, U. Blabla, M.Blabla}
\chapter{\protect\img{image-1.png}This is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long second entry for chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image: TOC example]

I'm not very happy with that, i want something like that :

[image]

The `image1-png` icon :

[image: icon]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the image to your `\authortoctext` command:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % Subsection mit Zähler (1.1) versehen

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{}  }
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }

\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\settocdepth{chapter}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[2]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\leftskip0em\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\noindent\imageintoc{#2}\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand\imageintoc[1]{%
 {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{%
   \includegraphics[height=30pt]{#1}}\hspace{10pt}}}}

\makeatother
\newcommand\authortoc[2]{%
  \gdef\chapterauthor{#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\authortoctext{#1}{#2}}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\newcommand*{\img}[1]{%
    \raisebox{-.3\baselineskip}{%
        \includegraphics[
        height=30pt,
        width=30pt,
        ]{#1}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\authortoc{G. Blabla, A. Blabla}{example-image-a}
\chapter[Entry for toc]{\protect\img{example-image}This an entry for chapter}
\authortoc{F. Blabla, U. Blabla, M.Blabla,F. Blabla, U. Blabla, M.Blabla,F. Blabla, U. Blabla, M.Blabla}{example-image-b}
\chapter[This is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long second entry for chapter]
      {\protect\img{example-image}This is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long second entry for chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but also i'm interested by changing this image A between the different entries in the toc using \img{...} :)

Comment: You  can add an argument to pass the name of the image.

Comment: I  try to add argument like that without success, i'm not sure how can i pass the image parameter, could you please update your answer, and after that i accept it ? : 

```\noindent\imageintoc#1\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand\imageintoc[1]{%
 {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{%
   \includegraphics[height=30pt]{#1}}\hspace{10pt}}}}```

Comment: You naturally need to add the argument to all your commands to correctly pass it around. I have edited the question with one suggestion how to do it.